# Chrome v14b - about:flags page not found

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

About a week ago, I updated to the latest beta version of Chrome, 14.0.835.159 (Official Build 100066) beta-m. I immediately noticed the "Experimental New Tab Page" wasn't working -- and ok, I was [warned](http://lifehacker.com/5667846/chromes-aboutlabs-renamed-to-aboutflags-adds-a-warning).

Now I cannot even open `about:flags`. Instead, I get a generic "page not found" message:

> **This webpage is not available**
>
> The webpage at **chrome://flags/** might be
>   temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web
>   address.
>
> Error 300 (net::ERR_INVALID_URL): Unknown error.

Weird stuff is bound to happen on beta versions, but am I missing something obvious? I can file a bug report on Chromium's [issues](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list), if not.

Comment: I have a similar problem on the non beta version 13.0.782.220, if I use the about:about page and click the link for flags and several others, I get that message, but it loads if I type about:flags (or others) in the url bar.

Comment: @Moab, thanks, I didn't even know of `about:about`. My version doesn't even list "flags" in that list. Interesting...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to their [blogspot](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/2011/09/beta-channel-update_08.html) entry, `about:flags` was removed intentionally, citing stability issues.

> **This release disables chrome:flags.**  We are currently investigating
>   some stability issues and are looking to see how greatly flags usage
>   contributes to our stability metrics, hence we are temporarily
>   disabling them.  To see what other changes went into this release
>   check out our change log.

The [Release History](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome#Release_history) page on Wikipedia states that the experimental "New Tab Page" will become the default in the next release, version 15. This isn't seeming like a popular decision, but at experiments should still be accessible for those running the [Dev Channel](http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/eula_dev.html).

See: [Blogspot entry](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/2011/09/beta-channel-update_08.html), [Chrome Help Forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=4b581475021b64ce&hl=en&fid=4b581475021b64ce0004acc40224418d), [Chrome Release History](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome#Release_history), [blog](http://randomland.net/zourtney/2011/09/chrome-aboutflags-missing)

---

**Edit:** the Beta Channel updated to 14.0.835.162 this afternoon, re-enabling the `about:flags` page. Consequently, the experimental "New Tab Page" (and others) are re-enabled.